# Javascript function not working without return

Tags: javascript

When i use return at the and of function it renders as i want but if i dont use return it dont render.

```js
const controlNext = function () {
  if (model.state.counterData.type === "work") {
    model.state.counterData.time = 300; //changes time data
    model.state.counterData.type = "timeout"; //changes time type
    renderClock(); //changes time data as min:sec and renders it
    clock.renderStatus("timeout"); //renders time type
    if (model.state.workData.currentWorkNum === -1) {
      return;
    } //if there is no work in query returns
    model.state.workData.works[model.state.workData.currentWorkNum].repeat--; //if there is work in query it gets one number down
    work.renderToList(model.state.workData.works); //renders works
    return; //if i dont use this return it dont render time data and renderstatus
  }
};


  listenNext(func) {
this._nextButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  func();
})}//controlnext is in this function as argument
```

Comment: it has another if block in function but other part works good.

Comment: How is the controlNext function getting called?

Comment: I'm guessing the part that is calling `controlNext` is waiting for a return value...

Comment: controlNext is in addeventlisteners function, does not javascript automatically return?

Comment: i have same function in setInterval and it works without return lol